# React Material-UI GridList cascading layout

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to use `GridList` component of the React Material-UI library in a pinterest like cascading layout?

I use Material-UI `Card` components as children for the `GridList`:

```
    const cards = props.items.map((item) => <Card key={item.id} {...item} />);
    return (
      <GridList cols={3} cellHeight={'auto'}>
        {React.Children.toArray(cards)}
      </GridList>
    );
```

The result is following:
[image: The result image]

I want to remove gaps in red circles. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS equivalent of you want is to have `flex-direction` set to be `column` instead of `row`, but [it doesn't look like the material-ui documentation gives you the option to change the order in which things render](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/grid-list).

I would try using a different container object or build something yourself since the Pinterest style layout requires some more complicated logic when determining where the next element to be rendered should go.

Answer (score 0):

This layout has a name: masonry, which is coming from the building constructions, because of how bricks are put together :) There is mui component for it:

https://mui.com/components/masonry/#basic-masonry

Copying sample here too:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Masonry from '@mui/lab/Masonry';

const heights = [150, 30, 90, 70, 110, 150, 130, 80, 50, 90, 100, 150, 30, 50, 80];

const Item = styled(Paper)(({ theme }) => ({
  ...theme.typography.body2,
  color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  border: '1px solid black',
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
}));

export default function BasicMasonry() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: 500, minHeight: 393 }}>
      <Masonry columns={4} spacing={1}>
        {heights.map((height, index) => (
          <Item key={index} sx={{ height }}>
            {index + 1}
          </Item>
        ))}
      </Masonry>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

[image]